# SSIS ASCII requirement: "Code page is 1252 and is required to be 20127"

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a requirement to export a database to a tab-delimited file in the ASCII format. I am using derived columns to convert any Unicode strings to non-Unicode strings. For example, a former Unicode text stream is now casted as this:

```
    (DT_TEXT,20127)incomingMessage
```

But SSIS is still looking for ANSI. I am still seeing an error at the Flat File Destination:

```
    The code page on input column <column_name> is 1252 and is required to be 20127.
```

This is what I have been doing to ensure ASCII is used:

- In the Flat File Connection Manager, used Code page "20127 (US-ASCII)"
- Used a Derived Column to cast data types
- In the OLE DB source, set the default code page to 20127.

Any thoughts?